# Angular momentum - maximum and minimum values for $m_{\ell}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, representation-theory, textbook-erratum

I want to work out the maximum and minimum values for $m_{\ell}$. I know that $\lambda \geq m_{\ell}$, therefore $m_{\ell}$ is bounded. In the lectures notes there is the following assumption:
$$
\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle=|0\rangle \\
\hat{L_{-}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle=|0\rangle 
$$
I think I understand this. Since the action of the ladder operators is the keep the value of $\lambda$ and raise (or lower) $m_{\ell}$, you cannot "go up" from $m_{max}$ or down from $m_{min}$. However, I do not understand why the result of the operation should be $|0\rangle$.

It turns out we can write the produt of $\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}$ as:
$$
\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}= \hat{L^2}-\hat{L_{z}^2}-\hbar\hat{L_{z}}
$$
Then we we evalute the following expression:
$$
\hat{L^2} |\lambda,m_{max}\rangle = (\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}+\hat{L_{z}^2}+\hbar\hat{L_{z}})|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle
$$
Since $\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle=|0\rangle $, then $\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle=\hat{L_{-}}|0\rangle =|0\rangle $. And 
$\hat{L_z}|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle = \hbar m_{\ell}|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle $. These two relations imply:
$$
\hat{L^2} |\lambda,m_{max}\rangle =\hbar^2 m_{max}(m_{max}+1)|\lambda,m_{max}\rangle
$$
Now I want to know how to compute $\hat{L^2} |\lambda,m_{min}\rangle $ since my lecture notes only state the result. My problem is that I will have $\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle$, but I can no longer say that $\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle=|0\rangle$. I tried to compute $\hat{L_{+}}\hat{L_{-}}$ and try to plug in the expression, but I had no success. How can I solve this?

PS. This is not homework, I'm just trying to derive the expression stated in the lecture notes.

Comment: $\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle=|0\rangle$ is not 0, it should be sth like $\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle=|1\rangle$, the next level (of ang. momentum) L+ and L- operators raise or lower the levels of ang. momentum, also cannot raise above max and cannot lower below min.

Comment: I have already mentioned this in my question.

Comment: The result is zero because this level has no states of the system that are compatible, i.e zero number of states of the system. Does this answer your question? Since L+ raised mmin to one (from zero), applying L- will lower the state back to zero

Comment: No, it does not. The result is a ket vector $|0\rangle$ not the number 0. And my question was on how to compute $\hat{L^2}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle$

Comment: Ket vector representing the number of states in this level, correct? It is a quantized harmonic oscillator-type creation-annihilation model, if i am not mistaken

Comment: In other words $\hat{L_{-}}|\lambda,1\rangle=|0\rangle$ or $\hat{L_{-}}\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_{min}\rangle=|0\rangle$

Comment: But how can you say $m_l =1$? It is only possible to express $m_l$ in terms of $l$, like $m_l=l,l-1,...,-l$.

Comment: yeap i took a liberty in the symbolim, see edited comment for explanation, one raises the next lowers the result is the "zero state"

Comment: Are you sure that $L_+ | jj\rangle = | 0\rangle$ in the notes? It should be $0$, because the subspace is finite-dimensional, therefore the next vector orthogonal to the rest must be 0.

Comment: Hi Ali. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lecture notes, or your transcription of them, are in error. You should have
$$
\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_\mathrm{max}\rangle= 0 \\
\hat{L_{-}}|\lambda,m_\mathrm{min}\rangle= 0
$$
That is, raising the maximum-projected state doesn't give you $\left|\lambda,m\right> = \left|0,0\right>$, a state with no angular momentum, and it doesn't give you a vacuum state $\left|0\right>$ with no particles in it. It gives you the number zero. This means, among other things, that the overlap of any state $\left|x\right>$ with $\hat{L_{+}}|\lambda,m_\mathrm{max}\rangle$ is zero.

As for your question about computing 
$
\hat {L^2} \left| \lambda,m \right>,
$
your lecture notes should contain enough information for you to prove that the commutator between $L^2$ and $L_z$ is zero:
\begin{align}
L^2 L_z \left|x\right> = L_z L^2 \left|x\right>, \quad\quad \text{ for any state $\left|x\right>$}
\end{align}
which means that the eigenvalue of $L^2$ *cannot* depend on the eigenvalue $m$ of $L_z$. In fact the eigenvalue of $L^2$ on a state $\left|\lambda,m\right>$ is always $\hbar^2\lambda(\lambda+1)$, which is the same as your result since $m_\mathrm{max} = -m_\mathrm{min} = \lambda$.

Comment: How does an operator acting on a (quantum) state have a simple number (in this case $0$) as a result?

Comment: @NikosM. Maybe a more precise way to put it is to use the properly-normalized version, $L_+\left|jm\right> = \sqrt{(j-m)(j+m+1)}\left|j,m+1\right>$. In that case whatever state vector is produced by $L_+\left|jj\right>$ is multiplied by a numerical constant which happens to be zero. That makes the state act like an [additive identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_identity). Compare to the state with zero angular momentum $\left|0,0\right>$, whose eigenvalue under $L^2$ is $\hbar^2$, or to a vacuum state $\left|0\right>$, which doesn't vanish under particle creation operators.

Comment: yeap this makes it more clear. my answer has same problem with this notation.